# Any way to automatic update controller and view code once model got updated - Already developed MVC application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one ASP.Net MVC data base first application. Due to some enhancement work came in I have to do modification to my DB tables and Add couple of new table as well.

I saw few tutorial and you tube videos. I found, they are deleting the existing model and controller -> changing the DB schema [adding SP etc...] -> then again adding new model and controller etc. However, I think, this is not the correct approach as my application is bit big[already on production], I can not delete everything and adding again back.

How can I do it? Is that MVC does not provide something so that I can update it from Visual Studio or refresh it so that my changes will affect? Any link would help. Hope my explanation is understood-able.
Along with I also wanted to know, is there any thing else I need to take care for these kind of enhancement?
Any disadvantage of using ASP.NET MVC?
 Thanks.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is quite broad and somewhat vague.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on .edmx file(added in models folder) to open it.Then right click on it and select update model from database and then press ctrl+s to save it.

Comment: Here my model got updated... But, Is there any way to update controller code and view code [with newly added columns/tables/SP], similar fashion(how I did for model) ? OR I have to modify my code manually as per my table[column] change?

Comment: You have to write code to update controller and view.